# Is there any command that enables to set for the whole program the number of decimals in a float variable?

Tags: python, variables, format

I would appreciate it if someone could tell me whether I can set definitely the precision of a float variable in Python. I mean a function like long/short for format in MATLAB. Thank you!

Please here is an example!

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mayavi import mlab
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from matplotlib import animation


from decimal import *
setcontext(program_context)
program_context = Context(prec=4, rounding=ROUND_UP)

a=.1
dt=.1

nx=31
ny=31
p=6

x = np.linspace(-p,p,nx)
y = np.linspace(-p,p,ny)


qx=2.0*p/(nx-1)
qy=2.0*p/(ny-1)

ax.set_xlim(-p,p)
ax.set_ylim(-p,p)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

U=-a*Y
V=a*X



xp = np.empty(11) 
yp = np.empty(11)

xp[0]=2
yp[0]=2

for i in range(10):

    xp[i+1]=xp[i]+dt*U[i+(2+p)/qx,i+(2+p)/qy]
    yp[i+1]=yp[i]+dt*V[i+(2+p)/qx,i+(2+p)/qy]
    print (xp[i], yp[i])
```

I obtain the following:

```
(2.0, 2.0)
(1.98, 2.02)
(1.956, 2.044)
(1.9279999999999999, 2.0720000000000001)
(1.8959999999999999, 2.1040000000000001)
(1.8599999999999999, 2.1400000000000001)
(1.8199999999999998, 2.1800000000000002)
(1.7759999999999998, 2.2240000000000002)
(1.7279999999999998, 2.2720000000000002)
(1.6759999999999997, 2.3240000000000003)
```

Is is possible to obtain just 4 numbers in the decimal part? Thank you for your help!
Strömungsmechanik

Comment: You might want to read this: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: Thank you Tobias. I would like something more practical than forcing the format by the command decimal each time I need a specific format. May I set the format short for the whole program as I can do in MATLAB? Thank you!

Comment: `setcontext(program_context)` has to come after, not before, `program_context` is declared.

Comment: Even if we put it after it doesn't change anything! I think it is so messy to impose Decimal for each variable! Thank you again for your help! :)

Comment: @Strömungsmechanik: agreed that having to declare each variable as Decimal is messy. Have a look at numpy's `around` function and the SO answer I've linked to below, which might be useful, but I don't know enough about numpy to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to control the precision of a number in a Python program you would need to look at using a `Decimal` number rather than a float. To control the precision of `decimal.Decimal` numbers you have to define a `decimal.Context` object and then activate it with the `decimal.setcontext` function. Once a context is activated it controls all `decimal.Decimal` numbers in a particular thread unless it is specifically overridden with a new `decimal.Context`.

ADDED: it appears that numpy doesn't play well with Decimal numbers. `numpy.around` may be a better fit, although I've never used it. For more details see this SO answer: [Better rounding in Python's NumPy.around: Rounding NumPy Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11975203/better-rounding-in-pythons-numpy-around-rounding-numpy-arrays) .

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> # create a `Context` to control decimal point precision
>>> program_context = Context(prec=4)
>>> # activate the `Context`
>>> setcontext(program_context)
>>> # from this point on all decimal numbers will be truncated to 4 decimal places.
>>> # you can control the rounding behaviour when the `Context` is created; for example:
>>> new_program_context = Context(prec=4, rounding=ROUND_UP)
>>> # activate the new `Context`
>>> setcontext(new_program_context)
>>> # other rounding options include: 
>>> # ROUND_CEILING (towards Infinity),
>>> # ROUND_DOWN (towards zero),
>>> # ROUND_FLOOR (towards -Infinity),
>>> # ROUND_HALF_DOWN (to nearest with ties going towards zero),
>>> # ROUND_HALF_EVEN (to nearest with ties going to nearest even integer),
>>> # ROUND_HALF_UP (to nearest with ties going away from zero), or
>>> # ROUND_UP (away from zero).
>>> # note that `Context`s only apply to numbers that are explicitly declared to be `Decimal`
>>> a = Decimal(2)
>>> b = Decimal(3)
>>> a/b # evaluates to Decimal('0.6667')
>>> c = 2
>>> d = 3
>>> c/d # evaluates to the floating point number 0.6666666666666666
>>> # also, if constructing a Decimal number from a float, the float must be passed as
>>> # as a string; eg:
>>> e = Decimal("0.6678") # evaluates to Decimal('0.6678')
>>> f = Decimal(0.6678) 
>>> # f evaluates to Decimal('0.6677999999999999491961943931528367102146148681640625')
>>> # integers, however, can be created directly; eg:
>>> h = Decimal(10) # evaluates to Decimal('10')
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html?highlight=decimal#decimal

Comment: Thank you Superjump. But I can't find the desired function in the website you mentioned. I want a function that permits to display the variables with 4 decimals not more. Could you help me please for that?

Comment: @Strömungsmechanik: I've updated my answer with some more details which should hopefully be of help.

Comment: I have tried to put these three lines but it doesn't work! Could you possibly have a look into the edited question? I have just added an example! Thank you!

Comment: @Strömungsmechanik: in your program you would need to define a=Decimal("0.1"), dt=Decimal("0.1"), nx=Decimal(31) and so on. Note that floats have to be specified as strings but integers do not.

Answer (score 3):

No you can't. Python floating points do not allow a customizable string representation
and they are *always* represented as `double`s. The only way to format them is to explicitly use a format string (like `"{:.4f}".format(1.23456789)` or `"%.4f" % 1.23456789`).

In pure-python you could use the [`decimal`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) module which allows you to set arbitrary precision for floats.
You can set the precision using [contexts](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#context-objects).

However operations on such floats can be quite slower.

If you are using [`IPython`](http://ipython.org/) as interactive interpreter it *does* provide a `%precision` magic that you can use to set how floats are printed:

```
In [1]: %precision %.4f
Out[1]: '%.4f'

In [2]: 1.2345678
Out[2]: 1.2346

In [3]: %precision %.10f
Out[3]: '%.10f'

In [4]: 1.123456789
Out[4]: 1.1234567890
```

(see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16866761/set-ipythons-default-scientific-notation-threshold) related question).

However if you are using `numpy`, which you probably do since it can provide a MATLAB like environment, you *can* set the precision on *its* numbers using [`numpy.set_printoptions`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html).

For example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.set_printoptions(precision=6)
>>> np.array([1, 2.123456, 3.123456789])
array([ 1.      ,  2.123456,  3.123457])
>>> np.set_printoptions(precision=10)
>>> np.array([1, 2.123456, 3.123456789])
array([ 1.         ,  2.123456   ,  3.123456789])
```

Note that you can provide a custom floating point formatter to achieve whatever representation you like.

(note however that this only changes how the numbers are displayed, not how many bits are used to represent them. For that specify the `dtype` of the arrays).

Comment: Thank you Bakuriu. Imagine that I have a variable vector x that I want to display. The command print gives 12 numbers in the decimal part. I am wondering if a certain set of format using a MATLAB environment could enable to display just 2 numbers! for each component. Thank you in advance!